# terminate called after throwing an instance of out std of range

Tags: c++

I wrote a code that extracts only alphabets, but I get an unintended error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;



int main() {
  string str1 = "Hello World!-";
  sort(str1.begin(), str1.end());

  int stringcut1 = -1;

  for(int z = 0; z < str1.size(); z++)
    {
        str1[z] = tolower(str1[z]);
    }

  for(int i = 0; i < str1.length()+1; i++)
    {
        int checkstring = str1[i];

        if(checkstring < 97 && checkstring > 122)
        {
          stringcut1 ++;
        }
    }

  str1 = str1.substr(stringcut1, str1.length());

  cout<<str1;
  
    
}
```

I wrote a code that extracts only alphabets, but I get an unintended error.

Comment: Why do you add 1 to length() ?  That will mean a string of length 1 is indexed at 0 and at 1, since you stop at 2.  That's out of bounds.  However, your exception comes from the call to substr, which is range checked.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr
Your `if` is always false (nothing is less than 97 AND greater than 122), so stringcut1 remains -1.  substr takes an unsigned position, and -1 is very large when converted, going out of bounds (it starts past the end of the string) and that causes the exception.

Comment: Don't use hardcoded numeric values for character ranges. `std::isalpha` will tell you whether `checkstring` is a letter. And if you don't have a requirement to change all the letters to lowercase, you can remove that first loop.

Comment: Note that some non-letter characters have values that are greater than the highest letter value; they'll get sorted to the **end** of the initial string, so the code needs to handle non-letter values at the end as well as at the beginning.

Comment: Please don't just repeat text to get round the quality filter. Please don't just repeat text to get round the quality filter.

Answer (score 0):

Seem to be three different errors here

1. `if (checkstring < 97 && checkstring > 122)` How many characters can you think of which have an ASCII code of less than 97 **and** an ASCII code of more than 122? Obviously that should be `if (checkstring < 97 || checkstring > 122)`.
2. `int stringcut1 = -1;` This count should start at zero, `int stringcut1 = 0;`. Suppose you don't cut any characters from the string, then at the end you are going to do this `str1 = str1.substr(-1, str1.length());` which is obviously an error. Incidentially if you want a substring to take the rest of the string then just `str.substr(n);` is all you need to do, no need for the second argument.
3. `for(int i = 0; i < str1.length()+1; i++)`, no idea why you are adding one to the length here, just `str1.length()` or `str1.size()`.

I suppose that if you fix #1 then the extra character being processed because of #3 is guaranteed to add an extra one to your count, and so the `-1` in point #2 would be compensated for. But that's way too obscure, just iterate through the regular characters of your string, and start your count at zero.